# should a strategy pattern always be implemented as a singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton, strategy-pattern

Should a strategy pattern always be implemented as a singleton in .NET/C#? Can you provide some example code for what this would look like in C#?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern.  It doesn't use a Singleton.

Comment: Neither does this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776819/Strategy-Pattern-Csharp

Comment: ... or this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern  This one is a pretty good example.

Comment: It seems to me that trying to cram the strategy pattern into a singleton in any language is a bad idea - it ignores the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @Neuronaut: Singleton isn't a responsibility at all... It is an instantiation pattern.

Comment: I don't see how they relate either.. so maybe a better question is "When should a Strategy Pattern be implemented as a Singleton?" (as 'always' isn't even close to relevant/accurate), which is really "When should a Singleton be used?".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually the strategy pattern is about have multiple concrete classes, each with a single responsibility, and then having a strategy to instantiate them according to needs. My point is that cramming all those responsibilities into a singleton is a bad idea. If the OP is asking about whether just the Strategy class (as opposed to the whole pattern) should always be a singleton perhaps that should have been made more clear.

Comment: @neuronaut: I think you can probably assume that's what the OP means.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I find it's generally a bad idea to make assumptions. Been burned by that (gave the wrong answer) too many times.

Comment: @neuronaut: Well, any answer trying to make a singleton out of a bunch of strategy classes wouldn't make any sense anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A strategy may have parameters or state. A strategy may be extended using inheritance. These uses imply having multiple instances of the strategy, so it's definitely not a good idea to *always* require a strategy to be a Singleton.

Comment: ah....if a strategy may be extended using inheritance then it should not be implemented as a singleton because a singleton should ideally be sealed, right?

Comment: Instances of subclasses are also instances of the parent class, so if you don't make the singleton class sealed you can end up with more than one instance of the it.

Comment: What does a singleton have to do with inheritance?

Comment: I just explained in the previous comment, @user2864740. If you allow subclasses you will most likely end up with multiple instances of the class because subclass instances are also instances of the parent.

Comment: There is a difference between a 'static class' and a Singleton.

Comment: Of course there is, but how are "static classes" relevant to this discussion?

Comment: Because it seems about as fitting as a sealed class. Any instance of any class - with any ancestry - can claim to be a particular singleton. It doesn't mean "one instance of this class, ever (with one static state)"; just that a particular 'singleton resolver' will always return the same instance (and generally exclusively so).

Comment: The usual definition of singleton is "a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object." Do you use some other definition of singleton?